# Thunderbird deleted all e-mails older than 14 days

Tags: email, thunderbird

A terrible thing happened to me. I used my e-mail account for ages and I accessed it through Mozilla Thunderbird. Then I had to reinstall my computer. I installed Thunderbird again and I added my e-mail account as a new account again.

Thunderbird downloaded all e-mails from the mailserver and then deleted all of them, which were older than 14 days. The e-mails are gone - I checked it through the web API, too.

What happened?! Is there anything I can do to restore my e-mails (it is a real tragedy for me)? I might have made a mistake during configuration, but how could such a thing happen without a huge red warning? Please, help.

Comment: If all else fails, you can try pulling the old Thunderbird profile out of your backed up data from before the reinstall. You *did* back it up, right? (The profile sits in `%AppData%`.)

Comment: @Bob Yes, thank you so much! I restored the Profiles directory, then changed the profiles.ini and I can see all my e-mails now. You really saved my day! Is there any way to upload them back to the mailserver?

Comment: If you drag them into local folders and back to the mailbox, assuming it's IMAP, that should force an upload. I'm not sure if you'll end up losing a bit of server-side info, though. Probably not.

Comment: What about the Trash folder, sometimes they end up there. Take a look at web interface

Comment: @emirjonb Trash folder is empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there anything I can do to restore my e-mails?

The [Recover deleted messages add-on](http://nic-nac-project.de/~kaosmos/index-en.html#recDelMsg) should be able to retrieve your emails, **provided you haven't compacted the folder yet**.

Another option is [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) from [Piriform](https://www.piriform.com/) which can recover deleted emails. There is a free version available.

Note:

Before trying any off the above, don't forget to close Thunderbird and perform a backup. At least make a manual backup of the files you are going to work with.

---

#### What is the Recover deleted messages add-on?

> The [Recover deleted messages add-on](http://nic-nac-project.de/~kaosmos/index-en.html#recDelMsg) adds "Recover deleted
>   messages" to the folders context menu (right click on the folder).
>
> It will work with any folder that has a mbox file (POP account, Local
>   Folders, or IMAP offline folders created via `Tools` -> `Account
>   Settings` -> `Synchronizing & Storage`) if you haven't compacted the
>   folder yet.
>
> It can recover messages whether they are deleted normally, or
>   permanently deleted using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Source [Undelete a message](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Undelete_a_message)

---

#### What is Recuva?

> **Recover deleted emails**
>
> Email programs like Outlook Express, Windows Live Mail, or Mozilla
>   Thunderbird don't store emails individually. Rather, they store each
>   folder as a database file. For example, there might be a folder for
>   the Inbox, another for Sent Mail, another for Drafts, one for the
>   Trash and another for emails you've saved.
>
> When you empty the email program's Trash, the email program empties
>   that database file. Instead of restoring the database file, Recuva
>   goes one step further and recovers emails individually.
>
> When you recover emails with Recuva, they appear in a compressed .ZIP
>   file (for example, Outlook Express.zip). You can use any standard ZIP
>   file reader (including one built in to Windows) to open the .ZIP file
>   up and see the emails inside.
>
> Each email is stored in a standard .EML format, which means that you
>   can import it to any email program -- not just the one it was sent or
>   received from.

Source  [Recuva - Features](https://www.piriform.com/recuva/features/recover-deleted-emails)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be an interesting add-on. I will try it.

Comment: @vojta Don't forget, before you start, close Thunderbird and perform a backup. At least make a manual backup of the files you are going to work with!

Comment: @vojta Answer updated with another recovery option.